# Is there a function or a method to return the positional value of a character in a list or string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

The assignment

```
 *Numerologists claim to be able to determine a person's character traits based on the "numeric value" of a name. The value of a name is determined by summing up the values of the letters of the name where "a" is 1, "b" is 2, "c" is 3, up to "z" being 26. For example, the name "Zelle" would have the value 26+5+12+12+5 = 60 (which happens to be a very auspicious number, by the way). Write a program that calculates the numeric value of a single name provided as input.*
```

Here's what I have so far

```
def main():
    nameString = input("Enter your name to find its numeric value: ")
    letters = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    length = len(nameString)

for i in range(length):
    pos = nameString[i]
    value = letters.find(pos)
    newValue = value + 1
    print(newValue, end=" ")
    
main()
```

The program as it is will take the name entered, go through the loop a number of times equal to the length of the nameString. What I'm having trouble finding out is how do I get the positional value of one of the characters of the name entered. Once I have that value, I need to add 1 to it, since A in the string starts at 0, assign that to a variable, such as newValue, then loop again, and ad the value of the next letter to newValue and so on then print it out. I can't seem to find a method or function, for a string or list, that will do this for me. This chapter of the text covers strings and lists so I should use one of those to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: `str.find` or `sequence.index`

Comment: Note that you don't need the `()` around the alphabet here. You can also import `string.ascii_uppercase`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, all "sequences" (including strings) have a `.index()` method that finds the position of a value in the sequence. For strings in participating, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

There is an equivalent method for lists and tuples.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That assignement is not about position. It is about the ascii value of character. ord(chr) returns its ascii value.

```
name = "Zelle"
val = 0
for chr in name:
    if ord(chr) < 91
        val += ord(chr) - 64
    else:
        val += ord(chr) - 96
```

val should hold the value now

Comment: It isn't about the ASCII or Unicode value. It's about the position of the letter in the alphabet. A = 1 B = 2 etc... I posted the question at the top.

Comment: Nice job. 
You should avoid using `chr` as a variable name since it is a python function. 
You can also avoid the if statement by using `.lower` before the lookup. 
Technically it is not really the ascii value that they want but you are correctly using that value to get the *position* in the alphabet. 
And finally it might be good to filter input so you are only looking at the letters of the word, not dash or space or Return. That could be a use of the if.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the ord values of the string as they follow a specific pattern.

```
def returnWeight(x):
    return ord(x)-64 if x.isupper() else ord(x)-96

name = input()
weight = 0
for i in name:
    weight += returnWeight(i)
print(weight)
```